# installing llvm bindings in haskell

Tags: haskell, llvm, cabal

I'm trying to install llvm bindings, but there is an error

```
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\TEMP\llvm-0.10.0.15520\llvm-0.10.0.1\Se
tup.hs, C:\TEMP\llvm-0.10.0.15520\llvm-0.10.0.1\dist\setup\Main.o )
Linking C:\TEMP\llvm-0.10.0.15520\llvm-0.10.0.1\dist\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring llvm-0.10.0.1...
Preprocessing library llvm-0.10.0.1...
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MXCoreAsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MSystemZAsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MSparcAsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MPIC16AsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MPIC16CodeGen
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MPIC16Info
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MMSIL
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MMSILInfo
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MMipsAsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MDebugger
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MCellSPUAsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MBlackfinAsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MAlphaAsmPrinter
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lLLV
MSystem
```

LLVM is installed, install with cabal

> cabal install llvm --configure-option --with-llvm-prefix="C:\M
>   inGW\bin\llvm"

Comment: Silly question: Did you install the real llvm library?

Comment: Yes, llvm is installed(on Windows).

Comment: I think your `llvm-prefix` is wrong. Do you really have the libraries in `C:\MinGW\bin\llvm\lib` ? If not, it probably should be `--with-llvm-prefix="C:\MinGW`.

Comment: It seems to be correct, because when I enter the wrong address knowingly increased the number of errors.

Comment: The llvm distribution for Windows does not contain the libraries, just the executables.  So you need to compile it yourself.  Please complain to the llvm maintainers about this (I've already done so).

Comment: @augustss, we're not going to provide the libraries on mingw. They are not portable across gcc versions & flavours (e.g. sjlj vs dw2 exceptions). Building all the variants is a maintenance nightmare and pretty confusing selection for users.

Comment: @AntonKorobeynikov That's a fair point.  But it also makes it a nightmare to use the Haskell llvm bindings, because you need to install mingw just to build the libraries.

Comment: @augustss, from the message I can see that mingw is already installed (in C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2011.2.0.1/mingw/), so it's not a problem.

Comment: @AntonKorobeynikov The mingw that comes with the Haskell platform is a very stripped down and specialized mingw that comes with ghc.  It's used to get a compiler toolchain for ghc.  It can't really be used to compile LLVM.  Instead you need to install mingw and msys, then configure, compile, and install LLVM.

Answer (score 2):

As augustss notes, you will need some source of libllvm for windows, which does not come with the binary distribution. As far as I know this issue is still not resolved. There are instructions around the web for building llvm from source on windows, which unfortunately still seems to be the appropriate approach.